# Is it sensible to assume that the investment theory developed arround the US market can be applied to the Eurozone?

Tags: united-states, investing, investment-strategies, european-union

Are investment strategies and policies that you find in popular investment books, such as "The Intelligent Investor", extrapolable from the `US Market` to the `Eurozone`?

If the answer to the above is no, does it make sense for Europeans to read books about investment that regard only the `US Market`?

Comment: Are there any aspects of these "investment strategies and policies" that you are specifically interested in? (average stock market return, asset allocation, etc...)

Comment: Specifically, the index funds / ETFs. Several times these books analyse the risk, returns, stability etc. of the `S&P 500`. I'm wondering if the same criteria applied to that index can be also applied to the `FTSE 100` or the `Euro Stoxx 50`

Comment: When the intelligent investor was written there was no S&P 500. I don't believe that he ever went into detail on any index, just individual stocks/companies. The same principles do apply for companies

Comment: @xyious I'm pretty sure that the new edition of the intelligent investor mentions both the S&P 500 and the DJIA